# No puedo grabar desde Java en SQL Server

Tags: java, sql

Buenas, tengo una aplicacion Web en la cual el front end es javaScript y el back java, la cual se conecta a SQL Server, tengo un SP la cual consulta los datos sobre una tabla, los cuales si no estan los genera a travez de una Funcion, la cuestion es que la pantalla del web me muetra los datos generados, osea el sp funciona
[image: Pantalla de salida]

Pero no graba los datos en la base, los genera, los consulta sobre la tabla en teoria modificada pero no los guarda, pero si ejecuto desde la consola de sql anda a la perfeccion. el codigo SQL es el siguiente:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPC_PeriodoTasaObtener]
(
    @idInmueble int,
    @anio int,
    @idContribuyente int
)
AS BEGIN
declare @valores int
set @valores = (select COUNT(idDeuda) from ValoresPeriodoTasa where 
                 idInmueble=@idInmueble and anio = @anio)

if @valores = 0 begin
    insert into ValoresPeriodoTasa(idDeuda,idInmueble,anio,periodo,montoPeriodo,primerVencimiento,segundoVencimiento,estado,codigoPeriodo)
    select codigoDeduda,idInmueble,anioDeuda,periodo,montoperiodo,primerVence,segundoVence,estadoDeuda,codigoPeriodo 
    from dbo.GeneraDeuda(@idContribuyente,@idInmueble,@anio)
end 

select idDeuda,idInmueble,anio,periodo,montoPeriodo,primerVencimiento,segundoVencimiento,estado,codigoPeriodo
from ValoresPeriodoTasa 
where idInmueble=@idInmueble and anio=@anio
end
```

espero que me puedan guiar a solucionar mi problema. gracias

```
public List<EstadoPeriodosTasa> obtenerPeriodos(int idInmueble, int anio, int idContribuyente) {
        List<EstadoPeriodosTasa> tasa = new ArrayList<EstadoPeriodosTasa>();
        Connection          connection = DBConection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement   st          = null;
        ResultSet           resultSet   = null;

        try{
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            st = connection.prepareStatement("SPC_PeriodoTasaObtener " + idInmueble + ", " + anio + ", " + idContribuyente);
            resultSet = st.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                EstadoPeriodosTasa elem = new EstadoPeriodosTasa();
                elem.setIdDeuda(resultSet.getInt(1));
                elem.setIdInmueble(resultSet.getInt(2));
                elem.setAnio(resultSet.getInt(3));
                elem.setPeriodo(resultSet.getString(4));
                elem.setMontoPeriodo(resultSet.getDouble(5));
                elem.setPrimerVence(dateFormat.format(resultSet.getDate(6)));
                elem.setSegundoVence(dateFormat.format(resultSet.getDate(7)));
                elem.setEstadoPeriodo(resultSet.getString(8));
                elem.setCodigoPeriodo(resultSet.getInt(9));
                tasa.add(elem);
            }
            return tasa;
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                DBConection.cerrarConexion(resultSet,st,connection);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return tasa;
    }
```

este es el codigo de java que llama al sp, ya tengo otros sp que le paso los parametros y me graban perfecto, este caso es muy particular xq paso los parametros se ejecuta una funcion, genera los nuevos campos, me los devuelve pero no me los graba, pero si ejecuto desde sql los graba y tambien los devuelve

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Si tu consulta sql anda, entonces podemos descartar esa parte, y el problema es dentro de java o javascript. Deberías postear el código relativo a eso.

Comment: este es el codigo de java que ejecuta el SP

Comment: @moloyoni en tu pregunta no hay una sola línea de Java o Javascript, así que sólo pones el código que estás seguro que sí funciona no podemos ayudarte

Comment: Pero estos valores `@idContribuyente,@idInmueble,@anio`  ¿dónde son inicializados en el código?

Comment: Yo no veo ningún `commit` en el SP

Comment: ¿Cómo estás manejando la transaccionabilidad de la ejecución del procedimiento desde Java? Por favor muéstranos eso.

Comment: Me parece que debieras colocar el código así: `try { connection.setAutoCommit(false); /*código del try antes del return*/ connection.commit(); return tasa;} catch (...) { connection.rollback(); } /* resto de tu código */`

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer un ingreso en una una base de datos desde java seria así

```
try{
  Connection conexion = new Connection();
  PreparedStatement pstm = conexion.preparedStatement("INSERT INTO 
  nombre_tabla(campo1,campo2,campo3) VALUES (?,?,?)");
  pstm.setInt(1,campo1);
  pstm.setString(2,campo2);
  pstm.setString(3,campo3);
  pstm.executeUpdate();

  }catch(SQLException ex){

System.out.println(ex);
}
```

En esta parte "VALUES (?,?,?)" van tantos "?" como campos vayas a ingresar dentro de la base de datos.Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

solucionado el problema era el codigo Java como ejecuto una transaccion que me devuelve una lista y no una simple consulta me falto poner el commit
el nuevo codigo java quedo asi

```
public List<EstadoPeriodosTasa> obtenerPeriodos(int idInmueble, int anio, int idContribuyente) {
        List<EstadoPeriodosTasa> tasa = new ArrayList<EstadoPeriodosTasa>();
        Connection          connection = DBConection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement   st          = null;
        ResultSet           resultSet   = null;
        try{
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            st = connection.prepareStatement("SPC_PeriodoTasaObtener ?,?,?");
            st.setInt(1, idInmueble);
            st.setInt(2, anio);
            st.setInt(3, idContribuyente);
            resultSet = st.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                EstadoPeriodosTasa elem = new EstadoPeriodosTasa();
                elem.setIdDeuda(resultSet.getInt(1));
                elem.setIdInmueble(resultSet.getInt(2));
                elem.setAnio(resultSet.getInt(3));
                elem.setPeriodo(resultSet.getString(4));
                elem.setMontoPeriodo(resultSet.getDouble(5));
                elem.setPrimerVence(dateFormat.format(resultSet.getDate(6)));
                elem.setSegundoVence(dateFormat.format(resultSet.getDate(7)));
                elem.setEstadoPeriodo(resultSet.getString(8));
                elem.setCodigoPeriodo(resultSet.getInt(9));
                tasa.add(elem);
            }
            connection.commit();
            return tasa;
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                DBConection.cerrarConexion(resultSet,st,connection);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return tasa;
    }
```

no solo devuelve la lista sino que ademas graba el problema en definitiva era en java